# HTML5 mode in new Angular router

Tags: angular

Where can i find any documentation concerning the activation of html5 mode in the new angular 1.4 router.

There is nothing on the [Angular Router gihtub repo](https://github.com/angular/router/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=html5&type=Code), or in the [official docs](https://angular.github.io/router/)

Comment: I don't see why you would have to do anything other than configuring $locationProvider, as you have always done.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

})();
```

Comment: Just a heads up that 'configuration' is not needed in angular 1.5 (as for whatever reason it breaks)